# Unable to upload doc and docx files

Tags: php

Here i am trying to upload pdf, doc and docx files. Pdf files are uploading well but doc and docx files are not uploading. I kept `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property in `form` tag. What's the wrong with my code.

```
if ((($_FILES["uploadjob"]["type"] == "application/pdf") 
    || ($_FILES["uploadjob"]["type"] == "application/doc") 
    || ($_FILES["uploadjob"]["type"] == "application/docx"))) {
    if ($_FILES["uploadjob"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: ".$_FILES["uploadjob"]["error"]."<br />";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadjob"]["tmp_name"], "jobuploads/".$_FILES["uploadjob"]["name"]);
        // echo $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $filename = $_FILES["uploadjob"]["name"];
    }
} else {
    echo "<br><br><br><center><font size='3' color='red'>Invalid file. Please upload only pdf, doc or docx files.</font><br><br> This page will be redirected after 5 seconds, Please wait................</center>";
    echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='5; url=jobopening.php'>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `$_FILES["uploadjob"]["type"]` Maybe the mime type for these files are not this one. I remember that for example doc is `application/msword` the official one.

Comment: I have done what u suggested. I have uploaded doc file only. It gave "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document".

Comment: You've your answer, the type is not right in your condition :)

Comment: OK, i have added ($_FILES["uploadjob"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") in if conditions. Now it is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Mime type of the document you are uploading, the rest of your code looks correct. You can check this with `$_FILES[]["type"]`. If the Mime type is different, add it to your IF condition and see if it works then.

If it still doesn't work, check that the filesize is under the limit set in `PHP.ini`. You can find filesize limits with `phpinfo()`;